my app script code is run very slow, how can make it short and faster
below are the code which run slow, how can we imporve this or any other alternative option to do this
function splitAndTranspose() {
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
 var lastRowF = sheet.getRange("G" + sheet.getLastRow()).getValue() ? sheet.getLastRow() + 1 : sheet.getLastRow();
 var currentRow = 2;

 for (var row = 2; row <= lastRowF; row++) {
   var dataB = sheet.getRange("B" + row).getValue().toString().split(",");
   var dataC = sheet.getRange("C" + row).getValue().toString().split(",");
   var dataD = sheet.getRange("D" + row).getValue().toString().split(",");

   for (var i = 0; i < dataB.length; i++) {
     sheet.getRange(currentRow, 7).setValue(dataB[i]);
     sheet.getRange(currentRow, 8).setValue(dataC[i]);
     sheet.getRange(currentRow, 9).setValue(dataD[i]);
     currentRow++;
   }
 }
}


Please add at least the programming language used. How are we supposed to know it? Besides, it is generally important for us to reproduce the issue. Otherwise you need to provide the minimum information useful so we can actually help you. Please read how-to-ask

You should avoid as max as possible to call your sheet, so avoid getValue()/SetValue() in a loop.
You can achieve the same result by getting all of your data in once: getValues(), treat your data, and print it back using setValues().
Hope this helps!
Cheers
